# Filter rows before .ToList() using LINQ and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have some tables:

> NotificationQueue

```
NotQueueId OrderId CreateDateTime      SentDateTime NotType
1          Order1  2020-02-25 10:37:17 NULL         Failure
2          Order1  2020-02-25 16:37:18 NULL         Escalation
3          Order2  2020-02-24 04:37:16 NULL         Failure
4          Order2  2020-02-24 10:37:17 NULL         Escalation
5          Order3  2020-02-26 10:30:17 NULL         Failure
6          Order4  2020-02-26 10:10:17 NULL         Failure
7          Order4  2020-02-26 16:10:18 NULL         Escalation
8          Order5  2020-02-26 10:10:17 NULL         Failure
```

> FailedTickets

```
FailedTicketId OrderId StatusId FailedReason     CreateDateTime      UpdateDateTime
1              Order1  2        Somereason1      2020-02-25 10:37:17 NULL
2              Order2  3        Somereason2      2020-02-24 04:37:16 NULL
2              Order3  3        Somereason3      2020-02-26 10:30:17 NULL
2              Order4  5        Cancelled        2020-02-26 10:10:17 2020-02-27 16:10:18
2              Order5  4        Succeeded Later  2020-02-26 10:10:17 2020-02-25 01:37:16
```

> Status

```
StatusId StatusDESC
1        Initial
2        Validated
3        Saved
4        Complete
5        Cancelled
```

Essentially what's happening here is:

1. Every time some ticket fails, it gets pushed to the *FailedTickets* table and is also pushed to *NotificationQueue* table and stays there so that some *Email sending job* will pick it up and send the email and update the *SendDateTime* column.
2. After the ticket is not resolved within 6 hours, a new row is pushed to the *NotificationQueue* table indicating that the ticket needs to be escalated.

The **output I need** is:

1. Do not return any tickets that are either *cancelled* or *complete*.
2. If a same *OrderId* has gone to *Escalation*, skip the row that was made for *Failure* altogether and only return the *Escalation* row.
3. Return all tickets that failed (if they haven't escalated yet).

Example output from using tables and criteria mentioned above:

```
NotType    OrderId Status    FailedReason CreateDateTime      NotQueueId SentDateTime
Escalation Order1  Validated Somereason1  2020-02-25 16:37:18 2          NULL
Escalation Order2  Saved     Somereason2  2020-02-24 10:37:17 4          NULL
Failure    Order3  Saved     Somereason3  2020-02-26 10:30:17 5          NULL
```

BUT currently I'm only able to acheive this:

```
NotType    OrderId Status    FailedReason CreateDateTime      NotQueueId SentDateTime
Failure    Order1  Validated Somereason1  2020-02-25 10:37:17 1          NULL
Escalation Order1  Validated Somereason1  2020-02-25 16:37:18 2          NULL
Failure    Order2  Saved     Somereason2  2020-02-24 04:37:16 3          NULL
Escalation Order2  Saved     Somereason2  2020-02-24 10:37:17 4          NULL
Failure    Order3  Saved     Somereason3  2020-02-26 10:30:17 5          NULL
```

with this code:

```
var skippableStatuses = new List<string> { "Complete", "Cancelled" };
var failedAndEscalatedRows = (from nq in somedbContext.NotificationQueues
               join ft in somedbContext.FailedTickets on nq.OrderID equals ft.OrderID
               join s in somedbContext.Statuses on ft.StatusID equals os.StatusID
               select new
               {
                   CreatedDate = nq.CreateDatetime,
                   NotificationType = nq.NotType,
                   NotQueueId = nq.NotQueueId,
                   OrderId = nq.OrderId,
                   SentTime = nq.SentDateTime,
                   Reason = ft.FailedReason,
                   Status = s.StatusDESC
               }
           ).Where(e => !skippableStatuses.Contains(e.Status)).ToList();
```

Now I probably can loop through these records and retrieve the ones that have *Escalation* status. 
But I don't want to return rows that I don't even need, so before calling .ToList(), I want to create a LINQ query to return only required rows and avoid looping altogether.

I'm sure there has to be a better way to do it, so I've turned here to SO!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is, doing some filtering and grouping your first table's data (`NotificationQueues`) before doing any join, something like this:

```
 var failedAndEscalatedRows = 

    (from nq in somedbContext.NotificationQueues.GroupBy(c => c.OrderId).Select(c => new
    {
         c.Key,
         CreateDatetime = c.Select(d => d.CreateDateTime).FirstOrDefault(),
         NotQueueId = c.Select(d => d.NotQueueId).FirstOrDefault(),
         NotType = c.Count() > 1 ? c.FirstOrDefault(d => d.NotType == "Escalation").NotType 
             : c.FirstOrDefault(d => d.NotType == "Failure").NotType,
         SentDateTime = c.Select(d => d.SentDateTime).FirstOrDefault()
    })

        join ft in somedbContext.FailedTickets on nq.Key equals ft.OrderId
        join s in somedbContext.Statuses on ft.StatusId equals s.StatusId
        select new
        {
            CreatedDate = nq.CreateDatetime,
            NotificationType = nq.NotType,
            NotQueueId = nq.NotQueueId,
            OrderId = nq.Key,
            SentTime = nq.SentDateTime,
            Reason = ft.FailedReason,
            Status = s.StatusDESC
        }
    ).Where(e => !skippableStatuses.Contains(e.Status)).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Salah, Thank you for the answer but what I'm looking for is that at any given time, a ticket can be in Failed state or Escalated state, and if it has escalated, I want the whole of escalated row, not just the `NotType`.